# "Blacklisted" from a field?

Tags: united-states, references, termination

So lets start this story from the beginning.  About a month ago I lost my first job (after having held it for about 2 years) after someone at HR found out my political beliefs from talking to a friend of my outside the company (to be clear my friend had no idea who is was talking to, no bad feelings there).  I have also had bad relations with the person from HR in question in the past.  Before we get into the bulk of this here, I would like to make a point to say that I am not inclined to tell people about my beliefs and around the work place I refused to talk to anyone about politics.  No one knew anything about this, and it was never a problem.

My "resignation" from the company was a bit of a rough cut, but I had good references from a few high level people in the company, including my CTO, so I assumed I was fine.  I have a bit of a niche specialty, but I have a lot of other marketable skills.

When I started applying to companies, I began to notice something kind of strange.  Initially people would seem eager about hiring me, and I would get a technical test/interview/whatever.  I would then get a phone interview that would usually go pretty well, but then after that radio silence would occur.  This happened with quite a few companies, even when I started applying to more general fields.

I eventually got a bit of courage and called one guy from a company who gave me radio silence back, and asked why I didn't get the job and what I could do better on next time.  I was told that I was "qualified but my reputation got in the way."

Is there any way to figure out what's going on and get out of this sort of "blacklist?"  It's not exactly like I have the ability to explain myself, and stating that this happened up front would probably get me instantly denied.

Comment: You should include a location tag. What you're describing, being fired or forced to resign due to your political beliefs, is likely illegal in many locales.

Comment: This person said your "reputation got in the way". Unless you are specifically applying to political organizations, this sounds like far more than just knowing your political beliefs. The only way I could imagine political beliefs having this much weight is if these beliefs are highly extremist and associated with violence. I think there is more to this you are not telling us.

Comment: I would rather not post my location, but I know my state (I live in the US) does not have any restrictions on this.  Also on the topic of by beliefs, it never caused problems at work until HR got involved, and I am not an activist or anything like that.

Comment: @N.TM Thanks, United States is enough of a location for this, which would be far different than say Venezuela. And the fact that HR decided to get involved tells me that these are not your average red-v-blue political beliefs.

Comment: It's possible one of your references and/or your previous manager is bad-mouthing you. You say the "resignation" was a "rough cut", can you expand on that? @DavidK Could be something like oil&gas and OP has very left-leaning ecological/political views.

Comment: Have a friend do a "verification of employment" call to your old company.  That should reveal quite a bit

Comment: It's not clear and frankly highly unlikely that you're blacklisted over politics. The usual reason is that they talked to people who didn't like working with you much or that you've developed an actually harmful reputation in your field (which is rare). But what's usually going on is that these employers simply have better candidates and you didn't make the cut. The slander question is off-topic here, as is asking for people to share their story. Check [help/on-topic] for more on that.

Comment: @Lilienthal I removed those two question from the end so that the main question is "how do I figure out what's going on and fix it?" That should be on-topic without the legal/anecdotal aspects.

Comment: @mkennedy Without getting into to many details here, the person who found out about this at HR has some fundamentally different viewpoints.  She is well known for being vindictive on occasion, and intervened directly to get me fired even though there weren't any conflicts in the workplace.  I have also had a personal conflict with her in the past.
RichardU I will try that soon, seems like a good idea.

Comment: @N.TM Those details about your past relationship with the HR person are very important. You should add that into the question.

Comment: You also might find this question useful: [What can I do about a malicious previous employer giving bad references?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23642/what-can-i-do-about-a-malicious-previous-employer-giving-bad-references)

Comment: @DavidK Good edit but it's still a very vague scenario here and assuming stuff like this based on one company's feedback is often a mistake.

Comment: Curiosity, you state that you have good relation with few high peoples. Did you had a good relation with your coworkers day to day? Usually, high profile people rarely spread news openly but news spread very fast among coworker and old coworker/friends

Comment: @SebastienDErrico I am very close to almost every from the team I worked with.  Its been about a year since I left and we still see each other pretty much daily.

Comment: @N. TM do you work in a niche market where the players knows well the others players?

Comment: I don't understand how the "hold" reason is relevant. The OP's whole point is that he's NOT asking about one particular company's policies. He's saying that this is a problem he has at every company he applies to.

Comment: @N.TM Specific details would be really useful here. How did you end up being fired? If you had good relations with senior people, and it was just one HR person out to get you, how did they manage to engineer that? How do you know that the HR person was behind it? How do you know it was about your politics?

Answer (score 7):

OK, those political beliefs may be getting in the way (for instance few companies want to hire a Nazi even if it is legal to be one), but what you have to do first is prove they were told by the HR rep as opposed to finding it some other way such as searching your name in Google.

I would suggest contacting a labor lawyer and asking for him/her to help you out. No matter what your political beliefs, the ACLU might be willing to help out. Probably you will need a legal person pose as someone getting reference to see what they say about you and then , the lawyer might send a cease and desist letter.

Another avenue for you is to look at the companies that employ others sharing your beliefs.

Answer (score 2):

So... accepting that you have the right to believe just about whatever you want to believe in the US... have you considered that maybe there isn't an organized conspiracy afoot to blacklist you? My experience is that companies simply do not talk to each other about employees because if they get caught they can get into a *lot* of trouble, and on top of that, HR departments are known to give out false information about people to rivals if said rivals are dumb enough to ask. My own experience is that in the little bit of interviewing I've done, people come in with resumes claiming years of experience in a given technology but turn out to not really know what they're talking about. If companies aren't even doing *that* level of vetting, I really, really doubt they're doing the things you claim that they're doing.

Instead, take a look at your own online presence. I assume that you are "known" for writing things from a non-centrist perspective online because, well, it's my experience, also that nobody gives a rat's butt at the vast majority of jobs whether you're a Republican, Democrat, or Libertarian. Places *do* care if you're inciting violence or promoting hate, and if I do a 5 second Google search on your name or your email address and find like 10 hits saying that you're a Nazi or something, then yeah, as an HR person I'm probably going to quietly put your resume into the recycle bin. I'm not saying you should stop being outspoken online - that would be beyond the purview of this site - but if you're going to be, you need to either unhook your name/email from these things (if you have an online persona, you should have a professional email address that doesn't reference this anyway, even if you are the most centrist person in the nation) or else accept the natural consequences that arise from people being so easily able to come to quick, damning conclusions about you from quick Google searches.